# Android device identification: differences between Android ID and UUID

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-identifiers

We are replacing the identification of Android terminals by abandoning the IMEI and evaluating alternatives.

It is acceptable to us that the identifier changes after each reinstallation of the app. What we would need is a guarantee that two devices can never have the same identifier.

We found several possible approaches such as:
ANDROID ID

```
String androidID = Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(cnt.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
```

UUID

```
String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

What is the difference between these identifiers?
In particular:

- With which of the two identifiers does one eliminate (or reduce) the risk/probability of obtaining the same identifier on multiple devices?
- What is the most persistent way to store the data in order to reduce the possibility that it needs to be regenerated?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen this article? https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Comment: More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions

Comment: I updated the question to try to be more specific. Thanks in advance for your contributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question contains more than one question.

> What is the best way to uniquely identify and distinguish numerous
> devices with Android 10 or later using Xamarin Android?

Unfortunately, there is no sure way to do this.

The most **practical** way I can think of. You can define the recording date as day month year hour minute second millisecond.

This question was discussed many years ago and remains [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id).

**UUID**

`128-bit` value used to uniquely identify an object or entity on the internet

**AndroidID**

On Android `8.0 (API level 26)` and higher versions of the platform, a **64-bit** number (expressed as a hexadecimal string), unique to each combination of app-signing key, user, and device.

> public static final String ANDROID_ID

Android ID's

---

> On Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher versions of the platform, a
> 64-bit number (expressed as a hexadecimal string), unique to each
> combination of app-signing key, user, and device. Values of ANDROID_ID
> are scoped by signing key and user. The value may change if a factory
> reset is performed on the device or if an APK signing key changes. For
> more information about how the platform handles ANDROID_ID in Android
> 8.0 (API level 26) and higher, see Android 8.0 Behavior Changes.
>
> Note: For apps that were installed prior to updating the device to a
> version of Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher, the value of
> ANDROID_ID changes if the app is uninstalled and then reinstalled
> after the OTA. To preserve values across uninstalls after an OTA to
> Android 8.0 or higher, developers can use Key/Value Backup.
>
> In versions of the platform lower than Android 8.0 (API level 26), a
> 64-bit number (expressed as a hexadecimal string) that is randomly
> generated when the user first sets up the device and should remain
> constant for the lifetime of the user's device. On devices that have
> multiple users, each user appears as a completely separate device, so
> the ANDROID_ID value is unique to each user.
>
> Note: If the caller is an Instant App the ID is scoped to the Instant
> App, it is generated when the Instant App is first installed and reset
> if the user clears the Instant App.

---

> **With which of the two identifiers does one eliminate (or reduce) the
> risk/probability of obtaining the same identifier on multiple devices?**

UUID

> **What is the most persistent way to store the data in order to reduce
> the possibility that it needs to be regenerated?**

I recommend cloud and server services.

Comment: Thanks ΓDΛ: you're right, I added more questions. I rewrote the question hoping to be more specific.
We already know that we need to adopt one of the two approaches indicated (Android ID or UUID). We are trying to understand which is the most advantageous between the two.

Comment: I updated my answer. 
Since there is no definitive answer to these questions, I presented my own ideas.

Comment: ANDROID_ID has situations that need to be taken into consideration depending on the API levels.

Comment: Our customer guarantees us that all devices will have Android 9 or later.
"The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device or if an APK signing key changes."
In our case we make frequent updates to the APP, but the APK signing key never changes.

Based on this information, Android ID becomes the most suitable solution.
Thank you very much @ΓDΛ

Comment: You're welcome.